# about labeling encoding in image's classificatition

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I always use one-hot encoding to label the classes within the dataset, and I see that there are also people using another way to label, such as "imagen1.jpg": [["dog", 0.93266], ["cat", 0.06734]]. Is this a way of labeling? Or should I switch to one-hot encoding, setting a threshold to determine whether a class is present or not in such an image?

Comment: The term of art you're looking for is "soft labels." Here's a search to get you started https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22soft+labels%22 Whether using soft labels is appropriate for your task depends on what your data represent, your choice of model, and what your goals are.